# How to use ember.js for client side with struts as server side?

Tags: web, ember.js, struts2

I have created an application of Student Details using Struts Framework
Now I am given the task to use ember.js Framework in the same Application for client side.
So Can someone explain how can I use both together?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated yourself you want to write two applications. One on the client side and one on the server side. With ember I can't help you. But as it looks like you can generate a `index.html` with all the needed resources with just one ember command and put these files on a normal (apache) webserver. This webserver will be the starting point for your users.

For the server side you will need struts and the [struts-json-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/). With that you can create an API that the ember client can talk to. You don't need to use any JSP sites in struts for this interface.

Maybe it could look like this:

```
+--------------------+   visits    +------------------------+
| Client Web Browser |  -------->  | Ember Apache Webserver |
+--------------------+             +------------------------+
          |
          |         JSON           +-------------------------+
          +--------------------->  |  Struts JSON Interface  |
                                   +-------------------------+
```

Ember and Struts can work together, but my personal opinion is, that it's not ideal. If you only have the ember client as frontend and don't want to use any other struts features I would recommend to use [spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), as it would fit your needs better.